# How to send udp data from server inside container to remote server?

Tags: node.js, docker, networking, udp

I have a udp server set up using Node's dgram module inside a container that is running on AWS. I have published the ports and I am getting data from remote server. I am currently logging into aws remotely and viewing the server logs on my system. I now want to send some data back to that remote server. There are a few problems that I am facing right now.

1. Source ip of the packet coming in i.e. the ip of the remote server is altered inside the container I'm guessing because of some docker NAT error. Basically, I need to get the actual ip of the remote server inside the container as I need to set source and destination ip when trying to send data to remote server. I hardcoded the remote server ip and port and tried sending data. From my server logs, I can see the data has been sent but it hasn't been received by the remote server.
2. When packets are forwarded from the default bridge to the host's eth0, does it alter the packet in any way? I also tried pinging the remote server from the aws command prompt and it wasn't able to receive any packet.
3. Setting the container's ip as the default bridge's ip. I've hardcoded it right now but I want to know if there's another way to do this.

Any leads to solving this would be appreciated as I am fairly new to docker. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can publish a udp port on the docker host similar to publishing a tcp port:

```
docker run -p 5555:6666/udp your-image
```

That will publish port 5555 on the docker host to the container port 6666/udp (these can be the same port number).

When accessing, you'll need to connect to (or advertise) your docker host address/name, not the container ip.

Comment: I've updated the question as I realised I don't want the docker host's ip but just the default bridge's ip. I've already mapped the public and private ports. Any help would be really helpful. Thanks!